# Export 'default' using index.ts

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I've got the following project structure:

```
build/
    build.ts
config/
    config.ts
    index.ts
...
```

The `config.ts` contains a default exported type like this:

```
export default {
    myProp: {
        someProp: "someValue"
    }
}
```

And the `index.ts` within `config/` looks like this:

```
export * from './config';
```

Now I'd like to import the config type within `build.ts` like this:

```
import config from '../config';
```

But when using it (e.g. with `config.myProp`), it tells me that `myProp` doesn't exist on `index.ts`.

According to the official module documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), this should work perfectly fine. Am I missing something here?

Comment: How about `import * as config from "../config";`?

Comment: @Granga Thanks, but same result. `PropertyXY` does not exist on type `typeof ...index`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In `config/index.ts` re-export config as such:

```
export {default as config} from './config';
```

Then in `build/build.ts`:

```
import {config} from '../config;
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid explicitly named exports because the entire `config/` folder is just 'one module' so there was no point in doing that. But you got me on the right track. I ended up doing `import default as config from '../config'` and it magically started working. So thank you.

Comment: The first line won't even compile for me. It states that "config" has no defined "default" property, even though the file *does* have a export default statement. Typescript v3.1.6

Answer (score 9):

It seems like there is a trend towards **not** using default export, due to the number of potential issues. The recommendation is to use named exports. I am myself happily following the convention to only use named exports. The reasons as shown [here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/defaultisbad) matches my experience on the subject.

But, should you still choose to export as default, then I think you should be able to re-export it in `config/index.ts` like this:

```
export {default} from './config';
```

Then in `build/build.ts` you should be able to do a

```
import config from '../config';
```